# Making (or passing) an <a href> php variable invisibly on a link

Tags: php

Is there a way to put a php variable in an  without it automatically being visible, like a GET variable?

```
<a href="myphpfile.php?variable=hidden">Some click</a>
```

I want the subsequent browser URL to be `www.myphpfile.php` (no variable visible).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This sounds fishy to me. Why do you want to the destination of a link?

Comment: Right now the user sees this in his URL:
www.myphpfile.php?location=KY or
www.myphpfile.php?location=FL etc
I would rather they just see:
www.myphpfile.php

Comment: I got that, but why do you want to do that? What's the reason?

Comment: The variable is passed to the php file to set the initial display. The displayed information can be changed, by the user,  to any of the other locations once the user makes a choice on the page.  So the continued display of the original location is confusing.

Comment: Is my only choice to use a form with post for all the links that go to this file?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, my answer might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a form for it with `method="post"` and style the submit button as a normal link using CSS.

That is if I understood you question correctly.

Comment: After digesting all the responses, I think I best stick to the form post.  Just wanted to know if there was a way to do it quickly in an "a href" line.

Thanks for your help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right you want to have something like this:

1. Start a [session](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) and write the contents of `$_GET['location']` into, e.g., `$_SESSION['location']`.
2. Redirect the user, e.g. `header('Location: myfile.php');`
3. If the user changes his location, start at 1

Answer (score 0):

You should use *<a href="fake" onclick="window.location=real">*, but I prefer use links as <strike>The Lord</strike> W3C has declared originally.

*Edit:*

```
<a href="javascript:goto(nice_url_like_thing)">;
```

Comment: I didn't realize this was going to sound like a "fake" or spamming trick.  I think some of you have taken it that way.  I'm not trying to fake the URL, I'm only wanting to hide the passed variable to avoid confusion on the page after some subsequent choice are made by the user.  

Is this crossing some ethics line?  I surely didn't mean to do that.

Comment: I also want to add that I appreciate the feedback.  I'm learning and need whatever help people offer and also appreciate any ethic guidelines as I learn.

Comment: I did not said that you want to trick, but a link, which leads not to the exact place where the URL points to, is a fake one. Also, some robots (Google, say) may interpret it as fake, and you will got penalty, and you'll be unhappy with it.

Comment: Thanks emO, I appreciate your comments.  I took them in a friendly manor and was trying to respond in same.  That's sometimes hard to convey.  Sorry if you took it the wrong way. Thanks!

Comment: As a retired SEO expert, I say, it's dangerous to do any trick with links. You can discuss this issue with me, and I haven't tought for a minute you wanna cheating with it, but we don't know and can't argue with Google's evaluation system or cheat-detector.